# Upgrade Windows 10 Home to Pro fails with error code 0x0

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I've been trying to upgrade a customer's Windows 10 Home to the Pro version but after the computer reboots to complete the upgrade I receive an unhelpful error that the upgrade couldn't be installed with an error code of 0x0.

Has anyone experienced this and any ideas what's causing the upgrade to fail? I've tried two possible methods of upgrading using the key but not the clean install method. The two methods for an "online" upgrade essentially take you to the same place - `System Properties` -> `Change product key` and the other via the Store but it brings up the same screen as the `System Properties` method.

I'm reluctant to do a clean install as this will add extra time I really shouldn't need to add if the "online" method worked properly.

The system is a Lenovo desktop so has all the usual bloatware.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Haha Whoops! Let me ask it!

Comment: Have you tried a "chkdsk" and to ensure all drivers, lastest chipset and BIOS has been updated? I have seen errors from the upgrade with outdated hardware firmware

Comment: Not sure this was worth a down vote because the fact an error occurs when one shouldn't should give it away...

Answer (score 3):

Uninstalling McAfee LiveSafe has fixed it.

Concerning that the underlying OS's  built-in upgrade facility is blocked by third-party software!

Comment: Glad you solved it!